# Object method with ES6 / Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using **node v0.11.14-nightly-20140819-pre** on Windows with `harmony` flag.

I have JavaScript object with two methods defined in its prototype:

```
function User (args) {
    this.service= new Service(args);
}

User.prototype.method2 = function (response) {
    console.log(this); // <= UNDEFINED!!!!
};

User.prototype.method1 = function () {
    .............
    this.service.serviceMethod(args)
        .then(this.method2)
        .catch(onRejected);
};

function onRejected(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

`serviceMethod` of `Service` object returns a promise.

When I use `User` object like below:

```
let user = new User(args);
user.method1();
```

`this` in `method2` of object `User` ends up `undefined` when called by `then` once promise is fulfilled.

I tried using both **ES6** and **Bluebird** promise implementation.

Why `this` ends up being `undefined` in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why `this` ends up being `undefined` in this case?

Because you're passing a function, not a method-bound-to-an-instance. This problem is not even promise-specific, see [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) for the generic solution:

```
….then(this.method2.bind(this))… // ES5 .bind() Function method

….then((r) => this.method2(r))… // ES6 arrow function
```

However, [Bluebird does offer](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) an other way to call the function as a method:

```
this.service.serviceMethod(args)
    .bind(this)
    .then(this.method2)
    .catch(onRejected);
```

Answer (score 6):

I should add that this is a generic Javascript issue and can also be solved using plain javascript features.  For example, you could also do this:

```
User.prototype.method1 = function () {
    .............
    this.service.serviceMethod(args)
        .then(this.method2.bind(this))
        .catch(onRejected);
};
```

This uses `Function.prototype.bind()` which is built into Javascript and present on every function.  This creates a function stub (which is what is passed to `.then()` and that stub will automatically reattach the desired `this` value before calling `method2()`.

Comment: this is what i ended up doing to keep things compatible with es6 promises

Comment: I ended up using this solution, and fat arrow syntax for cases where having a separate prototype method was too verbose.  I believe both are ES6+ compatible.