# Passing "this" inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am trying to learn about promises.

My URL will contain three ID parameters, e.g.

```
#org=123&num=145&denom=467
```

and I want to use these to select the values of three `select` elements on my page (each one with an Ajax source), e.g.

```
<select id="org"><option selected val="123">Birmingham University</option></select>
<select id="num"><option selected val="145">Maths</option></select>
<select id="denom"><option selected val="467">English</option></select>
```

The complicated bit is that I need to do an Ajax request for each ID, so that I can pre-fill the name part of the option as well as the ID.

Then once all three requests are complete, I want to continue to render the rest of the page.

I've got most of the way there, but I'm stuck on how to get the value of `this` inside the `getNumerators` function. Can anyone help?

```
setUp: function() { 
   // use hash to set this.globalOptions
   var _this = this;
   _this.setFormValues().then(function() { 
      this.setUpRestOfForm ...
   };
},

setFormValues: function() { 
  return _this.getOrgs()
     .then(_this.getNumerators)
     .then(_this.getDenominators)
     .then(function() {
        return true;
        }
    });
 },

getOrgs: function() { 
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'/api/orgs/?q=' + this.globalOptions.orgId,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
},

getNumerators: function(orgIds) { 
   // FAILS: Cannot set property 'orgIds' of undefined
   this.globalOptions.orgIds = orgIds;
   var url = '/api/subjects/?q=' + this.globalOptions.numId; 
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Any other advice on the way I'm doing this would also be gratefully received.

Comment: Can you provide further code on how do you use these functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object method with ES6 / Bluebird promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27149034/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Funtion.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)()/[$.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context

```
setFormValues: function() { 
  return _this.getOrgs()
     .then(_this.getNumerators.bind(_this)) //using bind() - supported in IE9+
     .then($.proxy(_this.getDenominators, _this)) //using $.proxy()
     .then(function() {
        return true;
        }
    });
 }
```

or you can pass a custom context using context option in ajax

```
getOrgs: function() { 
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'/api/orgs/?q=' + this.globalOptions.orgId,
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this
    });
},
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - the `context: this` option worked for me.