# Angular 4 - "this" is undefined on ngOnInit() even with arrow

Tags: angular, typescript

I have found a lot of questions about this kind of error and I'm exhausted to find solutions that doesn't work to me... Why the "this" is undefined here on the picture?

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class UsuarioCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario = new Usuario();

  mostrarBotaoResetarSenha = false;

  constructor(
    private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
    private autenticacaoService: AutenticacaoService,
    private menuService: MenuService,
    private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService,
    private baseService: BasesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const idUsuario = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

        if (idUsuario) {
          this.carregarUsuario(idUsuario);
        }

        this.popularPickListBasesUsuarios();
        }

    get isEditando() {
        return Boolean(this.usuario.id);
    }

    carregarUsuario(id: number) {
        this.usuarioService.buscarPorId(id)
          .then((usuarioJson) => {
            this.usuario = usuarioJson;

            this.mostrarBotaoResetarSenha = true;

          })
          .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
    }
```

[See here the 'this' undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw0Rw.png)

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATING**

At [Line 62](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgaJI.png), just before the line marked by the debugger, the this is defined, as this.usuario and this.mostrarBotaoResetarSenha.

However, at [line 64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAvNL.png), these all are undefined

Comment: have you define usuario  varibale?

Comment: Ok. I have avoided to commit the entire code, but it is there now

Comment: Are you sure it's `this` that's undefined, and not the service? It's hard to tell what you're circling in the image.

Comment: are you getting any error are it is just a break point?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @FrankModica, Yes, it is the this that is undefined and not the service.

Comment: @Gui `this` definitely should be defined since you're using an arrow function. See [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-this-undefined?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: @lealceldeiro its a closure issue having to do with the scope of execution inside the promise. I'm not familiar enough with closures myself to say more. But I my answer apparently solves the issue so... :/

Comment: @John getting `this` inside `that` definitely does the trick... but this really shouldn't happen because (as I said), the OP is using an arrow function, which keeps the `this` related to the same scope. Or...Am I missing something here?

Comment: @lealceldeiro arrow functions ["retain the this value of the enclosing lexical context"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). I'm going to just assume that the promise is providing its own "lexical context"

Comment: Also, FWIW, I think the hold that admins put on this question is completely inappropriate. To me, the problem you are experiencing is quite clearly explained. It's also clear what you *wish were happening*.

Comment: Are you using bluebird?

Comment: Thanks @John... it makes sense. Do you have any handy doc where could I learn how to identify which is the _lexical context_ or the _enclosing lexical context_ of an arrow function?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I don't, sorry. And I'm just making a guess that that's what's happening here. I just duck duck go'd "javascript arrow function scope" to find the bit about lexical context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding `this` within the `carregarUsuario()` method closure. Something like

```
carregarUsuario(id: number) {
  const that = this;

  that.usuarioService.buscarPorId(id)
      .then((usuarioJson) => {
        that.usuario = usuarioJson;

        that.mostrarBotaoResetarSenha = true;

      })
      .catch(erro => that.errorHandler.handle(erro));
}
```

## Update

Considering this worked, I'll give what little explaination I can. [There are some *waaaayyyy* better explainations on S.O. regarding javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and I'm only knowledgable enough to do some debugging myself.

Basically, the scope the promise was executing in was outside that of your component. I think the scope may have been defined by the`buscarPorId()` method? Not sure. Regardless, by saving `this` as the local variable (`that`), `this` was brought into the same scope as the executing promise.

Put another way, `this` is kinda magical / special in javascript and its meaning can change. By saving this as a variable (`that`), you ensure it doesn't change. I'm sure some javascript expert will cringe at this explanation :). Read the post I linked to. Its better.

Comment: It worked for me, I can continue the work. However it still without explanation.

Comment: @Gui I added what little explanation I can. I only really know enough about javascript closures to do some debugging of them. Some S.O. searches will come up with *waaayyy* better explanations for you. I linked to one of them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149227/6759854    This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `mostrarBotaoResetarSenha` as a class property?

```
   mostrarBotaoResetarSenha = false; // add this

   ngOnInit() {
    const idUsuario = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (idUsuario) {
      this.carregarUsuario(idUsuario);
    }

    this.popularPickListBasesUsuarios();
    }

    get isEditando() {
    return Boolean(this.usuario.id);
    }

    carregarUsuario(id: number) {
    this.usuarioService.buscarPorId(id)
      .then((usuarioJson) => {
        this.usuario = usuarioJson;

        this.mostrarBotaoResetarSenha = true;

      })
      .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have defined. Check again please, I have updated the post with the complete code